# How do I edit the authorization header of an HTTP GET request originating from a hyperlink (<a href> tag)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I have an Angular application that stores JWT tokens in localstorage to provide authentication. What I want to do is figure out how to grab this JWT token and insert it into an HTTP GET request, that renders as a completely new web page (NOT a returned object from an XMLHTTP request that displays in the same page...).

Is this possible? The only way I've found to do something similar would be to use basic HTTP authorization, such as:

username:password@www.hypotheticalwebsite.com

And I'm assuming I could pass in my entire JWT there.

I'm using Express.js to handle routing on my Node.js backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply readout the JWT from your locale storage and then insert the JWT to the Authorization Header or you could add it as a GET parameter.

I would recommend the header.

On the next side simple read the JWT out.

If the processing is needed on all pages of the express instance, do it in the express-middleware.

**Update**

If you want to use a normal link you must use a parameter like `?auth_token=12345`.

To add it was a header you can use `$http` and use a method in your controller.
For example:

**Controller**

```
$scope.openLink = function() {
    var config = {
        headers:  {
            'Authorization': '12345',
        }
    };

    $http.get("<your url>", config);
}
```

**View**

```
<a href="#" ng-click="openLink()">Test</a>
```

## Shielding Admin Interface

To be secure you should add roles in your api and only allow the administration relevant calls for administrators and also check on angular side if the user is allowed to open the UI with the role the user has. For angular there are a few acl modules like: [github.com/mikemclin/angular-acl](https://github.com/mikemclin/angular-acl)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. How do I insert the token into the header?

Comment: That command is the standard $http module that opens up an XMLHTTP request, and returns an object, correct? I want a regular link to a whole new page.

I'd like to avoid putting it in the url as a "?" parameter if possible

Comment: you can't set a header field with a regular link.

Comment: Gotcha. What I'm ultimately trying to accomplish is to make sure the "administrator" part of my web interface is completely shielded from the rest of my angular app. Can you point me to a link or explain best practices here to do that?

Comment: To be secure you should add roles in your api and only allow the administration relevant calls for administrators and also check on angular side if the user is allowed to open the UI with the role the user has. For angular there are a few acl modules like: https://github.com/mikemclin/angular-acl

Comment: I think this might be what I end up doing, but I was trying to avoid exposing the administrator API URI in the client side source code for non-admin's for maximal security. Am I being paranoid?